# updateSelectInput does not update in RShiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to update an input in my ShinyApp, with "Previous" and "Next" buttons. The input is a sliderTextInput and I use updateSelectInput but I cannot understand why it is not updating...

My inputs are created in the server part as the menu depends on the choice of the user.
With "print" I see that "res" (the updated input) has the good behaviour, but "updateSelectInput" does nothing, and the slider does not move.

```
require(shiny)
require(shinyWidgets)
require(ggplot2)

Dates_RUN <- c("04/09 12H", "04/09 18H", "05/09 00H", "05/09 06H", "05/09 12H", "05/09 18H", 
               "06/09 00H", "06/09 06H", "06/09 12H", "06/09 18H", "07/09 00H", "07/09 06H", "07/09 12H",
               "07/09 18H", "08/09 00H", "08/09 06H", "08/09 12H", "08/09 18H", "09/09 00H")

ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("meteo_type", label = NULL,
                  choices = c("option1", "option2", "option3"), 
                  selected = "option3"),
      uiOutput("submenu_meteo")
    ),
    
    mainPanel(
      (plotOutput("map", height = "600px"))
    )
  )
)

server <-  function(input, output, session) {
  
  output$submenu_meteo <- renderUI({
    print("Creation du sous menu")
    
    menu <- tagList(
      ##Choix de la variable
      radioButtons("choice_meteo_var", label = ("Variable"),
                   choices = list("Pb")))
    
    if(input$meteo_type == "option1") {
      ### Choix du membre
      menu <- tagList(menu,
                      sliderTextInput("Choix_membre", label="Choice",
                                      choices=1:50, selected = 1))
    }
    
    if(input$meteo_type %in% c("option1", "option2")) {
      ##Choix de l'echeance
      menu <- tagList(menu,
                      sliderTextInput("Choix_ech", label="Choix de l'echeance",
                                      choices=Dates_RUN),
                      tags$div(class="row",
                               tags$div(class="col-xs-6 text-center",
                                        actionButton("Ech_prec",
                                                     label = HTML("<span class='small'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left'></i> Previous</span>"))),
                               tags$div(class="col-xs-6 text-center",
                                        actionButton("Ech_suiv",
                                                     label = HTML("<span class='small'>Next <i class='glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-right'></i></span>")))))
    }
    
    menu
  })
  
  ##########################################################
  observeEvent(input$Ech_prec, {
    print("Previous button")
    vec <- Dates_RUN
    
    nb <- which(input$Choix_ech == vec)
    if(nb != 1) {
      res <- vec[nb-1]
    } else {
      res <- vec[length(vec)]
    } 
    
    updateSelectInput(session, "Choix_ech", label=NULL, choices=vec, selected=res)
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$Ech_suiv, {
    print("Next button")
    vec <- Dates_RUN
    
    nb <- which(input$Choix_ech == vec)
    if(nb != length(vec)) {
      res <- vec[nb+1]
    } else {
      res <- vec[1]
    }
    print(paste0("res ", res))
    updateSelectInput(session, "Choix_ech", label=NULL, choices=vec, selected=res)
    print(paste0("input ", input$Choix_ech))
    
  })

  output$map <- renderPlot(ggplot())
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the input you are creating is a `sliderTextInput()`, you should be using `updateSliderTextInput()`, not `updateSelectInput()`. Change your code to use

```
updateSliderTextInput(session, "Choix_ech", label=NULL, choices=vec, selected=res)
```

Comment: So obvious but so difficult to find ! I thought it was generic and I searched for a moment...